# Intellij Idea preview not working (Render problem)

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea

I've just started to learn how to create android apps, opened one of the patterns (Empty activity) and now having a strange problem. I can`t see anything on the design tab of the layout.

I'm using Intellij Idea 2019.2, gradle 5.1.1 and androidx library dependencies. I've tried to change this

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

in style.xml. Now I can see components in the tree, but not on the blueprint\design.

I have this error message:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: sun/misc/Cleaner
    at libcore.util.NativeAllocationRegistry.registerNativeAllocation_Original(NativeAllocationRegistry.java:130)
    at libcore.util.NativeAllocationRegistry_Delegate.registerNativeAllocation(NativeAllocationRegistry_Delegate.java:66)
    at libcore.util.NativeAllocationRegistry.registerNativeAllocation(NativeAllocationRegistry.java:119)
    at android.os.Binder.<init>(Binder.java:404)
    at com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub.<init>(IInputMethodClient.java:18)
    at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager$1.<init>(InputMethodManager.java:606)
    at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.<init>(InputMethodManager.java:606)
    at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager_Delegate.getInstance(InputMethodManager_Delegate.java:43)
    at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.getInstance(InputMethodManager.java:681)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderAction.setUp(RenderAction.java:245)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderAction.init(RenderAction.java:133)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.init(RenderSessionImpl.java:163)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:383)
    at com.android.tools.idea.layoutlib.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:193)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:511)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.lambda$inflate$4(RenderTask.java:640)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

The app itself works good on the emulated android, but I want to know if there is a way to solve this error.

Update. Components become visible in the tree only after using "Clean Project"

Comment: Please report per https://developer.android.com/studio/report-bugs.html.

Comment: I`m not sure that it is a bug. It seems like I haven`t installed some library, I just don`t know which one I need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bug in 2019.2 and it has already been reported: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-219113

Also: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-219232 (same issue, different stack trace).

I had the same problem after upgrading so I went back to 2019.1.3 which works. So it seems that the only solution is to downgrade, until an update comes out.